# Random sample from a poisson distribution

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, random-variable

I am helping a student with stats homework.  This stuff was about 20 years ago for me.

............

Assume that the number of nucleotide base substitutions in a gene over a certain time period follows a Poisson distribution.  Assume that the probability of there being no nucleotide base substitutions over this period is 0.1

a) Calculate the mean for the random variable measuring the number of nucleotide base substitutions in the gene.

```
 I'm feeling confident about this part. (If this confidence is misplaced, let me know.) 
     P(X=0) = 0.1  --> solve for lambda -->  lambda = E(X) = 2.3
```

b)  Calculate the probability that there are less than two nucleotide base substitutions in the gene.

```
 I think I'm ok here too...
     P(X<2) = P(X=1) + P(X=0) = 0.33
```

c) For a random sample of 36 genes, approximate the probability that the average number of nucleotide base substitutions is less than 2.

```
 Here I'm unsure.  Binomial distribution with n=36, p=0.33...?
```

Comment: I would have thought you want the probability of the total number of nucleotide base substitutions being $71$ or less.  I would use a Poisson distribution with parameter $36 \lambda$.  That might be approximated by a normal distribution being $71.5$ or less, given a mean of  $36 \lambda$ and a standard deviation of $\sqrt{36 \lambda}$

Comment: Thank you, Henry. I was thinking that the answer from part (b) was required.